# What is the word for someone who is "transcended"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, orthography

This word should have the word "transcend" as its root, and it should describe humans who have improved intelligence and physical abilities (power, stamina, illness resistance, etc) by way of genetic engineering.

The dictionaries I checked didn't have the answer, yet I remember seeing such a word in trans-humanism literature. Maybe "**transcendient**" or something sounding similar to it.

Comment: transcended does not "describes humans who through genetic engineering have improved intelligent and physical abilities" outside maybe a particularly narrrow field such as Comics.  It just mean "something that goes beyond the limit". They are tons of synonyms. Put the word you're looking for in an example  sentence that we can help you.

Comment: You are quite right, however I'm planning to use it in a science-fiction/fantasy writing project and this word would describe the mechanics in this lore much more better.

Comment: Were you thinking 'transcendent'?

Comment: No, 'transcendent' is an adjective. I'm looking for it's object form(someone who has gained this attribute).

Comment: Anything wrong with transcendency?

Answer (score 3):

"Transhuman" (very closely related to the "trans-humanism" that you mentioned) may fit.

> Transhuman or trans-human is the concept of an intermediary form
>   between human and posthuman.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transhuman) In other words, a transhuman is a
>   being that resembles a human in most respects but who has powers and
>   abilities beyond those of standard humans.[2] These abilities might
>   include improved intelligence, awareness, strength, or durability.
>   Transhumans sometimes appear in science-fiction as cyborgs or
>   genetically-enhanced humans.

[-Transhuman on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transhuman)

Comment: Thank for the answer, "Transhuman" does have this meaning. however it doesn't fully converge with the concept which I had in my mind. in the work of fiction that I'm writing this group is considered as a different species from humans.

Answer (score 0):

The proper word is *Transcendent*. "He is transcendent or the transcendent one."

> **Transcendent:** Surpassing others; preeminent or supreme.
>
>  [[The Free Dictionary]](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/transcendent)

Answer (score 0):

Transhumanism is something of a niche subject and which is riffing of a resurgence of eugenics - people having forgotten what the last wave of eugenics thinking entailed.

It's a had a little bit of hype in the media but it seems very much a story of hype over hope. This is why you have found no such word in the dictionaries that you've looked at. It's simply not taken very seriously.